# Why there is not Hinduism in Europe, Africa, N.A, S.A, Australia?

Tags: history

Hinduism is only in few country in Asia. Is that mean All God or Goddess born in India only for India ?

Comment: As Hollywood movies are made in USA, aliens always attack USA. Similarly, the stories of Gods/Goddesses are documented in Indian subcontinent, that's why they always have Indian background. In reality, any God (Deva) will belong to entirety of population. The world has shrunk in last few centuries. Earlier people had a narrow view of world.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my understanding: The main reason why Bhagavan comes on this earth is to fulfill the wishes of his Bhakt. He is capable of killing some evil or making balance without even coming to earth. He does that as part of coming to earth but that is not the main reason.

Bhagavan comes on the earth to perform the lilas, and he takes birth where his devotees reside. If there are true devotees reside in the places you mentioned he'll go there. he's not bound to any country or place. **He is bound to his devotees.**

He performs the lila based on the wishes of his bhakt, after comming here he eats with them he play with them, he fight with them, he does all the human like activities. only to fulfil the wishes of bhakt. *And for the future generation*. if in the future someone seeks the god, he can feel his presence while reading or talking about him.

Bharat is considered as one of the most spiritual country, where lots of Mumuxu lives. This is the only country where you'll find many people seeking the god or saint.

Its an obvious why he comes to Bharat khand, He'll alwasy go where people calles him.

Thank You & Jay Swaminarayan.
Nixit